# Jenkins file, check if Globals variable exists

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have jenkinsfile with defined Globals varible for timeout

```
class Globals {
    static String TEST_TIMEOUT = ""
}
```

I am using functions from shared library
I am using the global variable to set a timeout for function. Since the shared library used by other projects that doesn't define the Globals variable I defined environment variable in the function file to be used as default value for time out.

```
env.TESTS_TIME_OUT="10080"
```

Then in function I want to check if Globals variable exists, I want to use the value as time out, if not the to use the default value.

```
if(Globals.TEST_TIMEOUT){
   env.TESTS_TIME_OUT= "${Globals.TEST_TIMEOUT}"   
}
timeout(time: "${env.TESTS_TIME_OUT}", unit: 'MINUTES') {
.
.
.
}
```

I`ve done it before with success on env parameters, but this time I am getting an error

```
No such field found: field java.lang.Class TEST_TIMEOUT
```

Any ideas how to solve this ? Or Any other way to check if Globals variable exists ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` which will be thrown if either `Globals` or `Globals.TEST_TIMEOUT` does not exist:

```groovy
try {
    env.TESTS_TIME_OUT = Globals.TEST_TIMEOUT
}
catch( groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException e ) {
    env.TESTS_TIME_OUT = "10080"
}
```

You could even move this pattern into a generic function...

```groovy
def getPropOrDefault( Closure c, def defaultVal ) {
    try {
        return c()
    }
    catch( groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException e ) {
        return defaultVal
    }
}
```

... which could be called like this:

```groovy
env.TESTS_TIME_OUT = getPropOrDefault({ Globals.TEST_TIMEOUT }, '10080')
```

This could be useful if there are many different globals that you want to treat similar. Safes you from writing many `try`/`catch` blocks.

The closure is required to make sure that the expression `Globals.TEST_TIMEOUT` will be evaluated inside of the `try`/`catch` block of `getPropOrDefault` instead of before the function call.